# Android - Passing a variables to another activity

Tags: android

I want to pass a Variable to my DBConnector.Java where I am executing an SQLite query but I am not sure how to do that and need some help.

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id) 
    {
                spinnerRub.setSelection(position);      
            myRub = (String) spinnerRub.getSelectedItem();

    }
```

Now I want to pass myRub to my DBConnector.Java where I have:

```
public List<String> getAllCapabilities1()
{             

List<String> Caps = new ArrayList<String>();

                String selectQuery = "SELECT Cap_Name FROM capability where Rub_ID = 'myRub'";

            SQLiteDatabase database = this.dbOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase();
            //Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
            Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
            // looping through all rows and adding to list
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) 
            {
                do 
                {
                  Caps.add(cursor.getString(0));
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }

            // closing connection
            cursor.close();
            database.close();

            // returning lables
            return Caps;
        }
```

But I am struggling to do that and need help.

Comment: Use Shared preference or pass data with intent

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Intent to pass your data :

```
  i.putExtra("myRub",myRub);
```

where `i` is `Intent` object.

Retrieve it in other Activity using

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
String a = extras.getString("myRub");
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I am getting this error in DBConnector.java
"The method getExtras() is undefined for the type Object" 
Can you please tell me why I am getting this error? Thanks.

Comment: what is DBConnector.java? What does it extend? If it is a class you have written? Can't you just create a public method which accepts a string?

Comment: @DeanWild its just a Class and extends nothing and my method is a public method as you can see but I am not sure what exactly i am missing.

Comment: Try using `getIntent().getStringExtra("myRub")` to retrieve vslue in second activity!

Answer (score 1):

Modify this in your dbconnetion.java file and pass myrub via method or sharedpref

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT Cap_Name FROM capability where Rub_ID = '"+myRub+"'";
```

Between two activity

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.putExtra("myrub", "This value one for ActivityTwo ");
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: Thanks for the correction but i also want to know to pass the values between to these 2 activities.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample to pass data to an activity and retriev

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClass(this, New.class);

Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putInt("action", nResponse ); // integer value
b.putString("homename", sHomeName); // string value
intent.putExtras(b);
startActivity(intent);
```

in you oncreate method of new.class please follow

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
if( b != null ){
    nAction = b.getInt("action");
    sHomeName = b.getString("homename");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your activity (im assuming you have a reference to dbConnector?) :

```
spinnerRub.setSelection(position);      
myRub = (String) spinnerRub.getSelectedItem();
dbConnector.setMyRub(myRub);
```

In DBConnector.java

```
public void setMyRub(String myRub){
    // do what you need to do with myRub
}
```

Answer (score -1):

use intents to pass data between activities

```
   Intent intent = new Intent(yourActivity.this, DBConnector.class);
   intent.putExtra("myRub", myRub);
   startActivity(intent);
```

and use `getIntent().getExtras()` to get it back

Comment: -1 for calling an activity, he is just asking to pass a value

Comment: @Muhammad Faraz with reference to "Thanks for the correction but i also want to know to pass the values between to these 2 activities." comment of the answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/15245448/1273336, I have written code to pass data between activities and retrieve.
Anyways, I used to consider the comments also while answering :)